# Why must gparted be run as root?

Tags: gparted

My user has access to USB-block devices (member of group plugdev). But even so gparted needs to be run as root:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdd
brw-rw---- 1 root plugdev 8, 48 Jul 17 19:05 /dev/sdd
$ gparted /dev/sdd
(requires root)
```

Is there any technical reason for this?

I have a full disk image including partition table in a file. Running gparted on this fails, so I instead have to do the `losetup -Pf` circus.

Is there any technical reason for this?

Comment: Hey Ole, is it correct that I see two questions in here (1. why does gparted need root although it actually shouldn't need root privileges? 2. Why does gparted refuse to open files instead of block devices?)? In that case, I think Artem gave a really good answer to the first question, might be worth moving the other question to a new question post!

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a bug which is worth reporting ;-) as `parted` on the other hand does allow to work with drives which you have access to without switching to the root account.

Asking for root permissions is the default mode of action for the application regardless of permissions:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/blob/master/src/main.cc#L52

```c
    //check UID
    if ( getuid() != 0 )
    {
        const Glib::ustring error_msg(_("Root privileges are required for running GParted"));
        std::cerr << error_msg << std::endl;

        Gtk::MessageDialog dialog(error_msg, false, Gtk::MESSAGE_ERROR, Gtk::BUTTONS_OK);
        dialog .set_secondary_text(
                _("Since GParted is a powerful tool capable of destroying partition tables and vast amounts of data, only root may run it.") ) ;
        
        dialog .run() ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

TLDR: it's how its developers believe it's meant to be run :-)

Comment: It's possible that parted has other uses for the root privileges that it needs (such as making the kernel re-read the partition table after editing). This is just a guess on my part, I'm not sure that it does.